# Hibernate after suspend stopped working in 17.10

Tags: suspend, 17.10, hibernate

After updating from Ubuntu 17.04 to 17.10 hibernate after suspend (hybrid suspend) stopped working. Since switching to systemd I used this solution https://wiki.debian.org/SystemdSuspendSedation (after the solution with a script in /etc/pm/sleep.d also stopped working) but now my computer only enters suspend mode and stays there forever.

`systemctl hibernate` is working and I don't have a clue why it's not working any more.

How do I make hibernate after suspend working again?

Additional information: I'm using the `tuxonice` kernel.

***edit:***
What I recently found out is that `systemctl suspend` and `sudo pm-suspend` seem to do different things in Ubuntu 17.10, as when I use `sudo pm-suspend` the old script in /etc/pm/sleep.d works as intended but the systemd style script still does nothing.

Comment: Do you have a swap file or swap partition?

Comment: How much RAM do you have, and how big is your swap partition?

Comment: I always was using a swap partition that always worked fine. RAM is 16GB, swap roughly 17GB. But the thing is: it worked before.

Comment: But we don't know the conditions under which it worked. After a fresh reboot, hibernate would work because there is enough swap space to store the RAM. After the system is in use, there may not be enough swap to store both the RAM and existing SWAP in the partition.

Comment: As swap is only used if the RAM is full and I barely use half of it there can't be a problem of the swap partition being to small.

Comment: Swap is not only used if the RAM is full, just run `free -h` after having a system booted for a couple hours, and you'll see that swap is used even thought there is still plenty of RAM free.

Comment: swappiness is set to 10 so there shouldn't be barely any swapping and therefore enough space for hibernation. As I said it worked smoothly before, for several years.

Comment: When the screen hibernates but then doesen't wake up from the hibernation can you access a `TTY` by clicking Crtl + alt + f2?

Comment: Sorry, but you don't seem to understand my problem, please read about hibernate after suspend first (for example https://askubuntu.com/questions/12383/how-to-go-automatically-from-suspend-into-hibernate).