# Hibernate from Kubuntu menu doesn't work

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, kde, hibernate

I have Kubuntu 16.04. If I try to hibernate my system to disc, nothing happens, there is nothing in /var/log/syslog, the only what I see this message in my .xession_errors:

```
powerdevil: Suspend session triggered with QMap(("Explicit", QVariant(bool, true))("Type", QVariant(uint, 2)))
```

However if I start hibernate from konsole, it works perfectly:

```
sudo pm-hibernate
```

What could be the problem.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036080/howto-enable-hibernate-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Dear @cmak.fr: The link above is not above my problem. Hibernating is working, but not from the KDE menu.