# Automatic shutdown after suspend Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, suspend, shutdown, time, automatic

Ubuntu never shuts down or hibernates even after a long time in suspend mode.  I always have to turn on and off my laptop. Is there a way to automatically turn it off after a certain amount of time like under Windows?

Comment: It's not clear for me what it the problem and what you are asking. Please take your time to explain precisely the steps you follow, what are the current results and what you expect. Beside that, please provide more information, for eg editing your question and adding the output of this commands: `inxi -SMI -! 31 && journalctl -b0 -k -p3 && grep GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT /etc/default/grub`.

Comment: okey look yesterday i turn on my laptop and did my work after that i suspand my laptop(go to sleep not turn off) and i forgot to turn off it at night i saw my laptop was on suspand mode and wasent go sleep its bad, windows isnt looks like ubuntu its automatic going to hibernate, i want way to do this in ubuntu can you help me

Comment: 1. Please don't extend the question in the comments area. Edit your question and add it there. Also please add the output of the mentioned command. 2. If I understand you correctly the question is: Is there a way to automatically move from sleep (ACPI S3) to hibernate (S4), or directly power off (G3) at certain point? [ACPI modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface#Global_states).

Comment: I think your question has a [duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12383/how-to-go-automatically-from-suspend-into-hibernate) that might resolve your issue (and mine).

Answer (score 0):

Download dconf editor and edit `/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power/`. Change `sleep-inactive-ac-timeout`, `sleep-inactive-ac-type`, `sleep-inactive-battery-timeout`, `sleep-inactive-battery-type` as you want.

You can alternatively try these. https://www.ostechnix.com/auto-shutdown-reboot-suspend-hibernate-linux-system-specific-time/