# xfce4-power-manager suspend to hibernate option?

Tags: suspend, xfce, hibernate, xfce4-power-manager

I'd like to be able to suspend-then-hibernate automatically with `xfce4-power-manager`, though I'm not sure if this is possible.

I believe this is a permission error with `polkit1` because:

```
$ xfce4-power-manager --dump
---------------------------------------------------
       Xfce power manager version 1.6.1
With policykit support
With network manager support
---------------------------------------------------
Can suspend: True
Can hibernate: False
Authorized to suspend: True
Authorized to hibernate: False
Authorized to shutdown: True
Has battery: True
Has brightness panel: True
Has power button: True
Has hibernate button: True
Has sleep button: True
Has LID: True
```

My polkit`settings under`/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.login1.policy`are identical for suspend and hibernate, so it doesn't make much sense when`xfce-power-manager` can't access hibernate options.

According to [How to go automatically from Suspend into Hibernate?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12383/how-to-go-automatically-from-suspend-into-hibernate): I've created `/etc/systemd/sleep.conf` and tested it.
The following command does work (suspend and then hibernates according to `sleep.conf`):

```
sudo systemctl suspend-then-hibernate
```

But this does not work when I use `xfce4-power-manager` to do the suspension.

A post I found ([How to go automatically from Suspend into Hibernate?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12383/how-to-go-automatically-from-suspend-into-hibernate)) is similar, but is not exactly what I'm trying to do. I don't care about lid closed operation, I want everything time related.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem, and found your question before I stumbled on the answer:

> xfconf-query -c xfce4-power-manager -p /xfce4-power-manager/logind-handle-lid-switch -n -t bool -s true

This page is where I found the answer:

> https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-power-manager/faq

If you want everything time related, then you can set them with settings in systemd and logind.conf

Here's a place to start:

> https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd#Power_management

I hope this helps you!