# XPS 13 9310 2 in 1 Sleep Problems

Tags: suspend, power-management, battery

I have been trying to get my system to properly sleep, however I can't figure out what the problem is and I also couldn't find any resources addressing my issue.

So the issue is, when i close the lid the system will briefly go to sleep ( I can tell that by the fans turning off ) , however after a while the system wakes up again (and the screen turns on too) while the lid is still closed. A while after that the system goes to sleep again, which causes the system to constantly sleep and wake up, causing a lot of battery drain.

Interestingly, the system does not seem to wake up from sleep if I constantly move the laptop physically, which led me to believe that the issue is somehow related to an accelerometer or maybe to its driver.

I have also tried Archlinux to see if the newer kernel and newer drivers would fix the issue. Indeed this problem does not occur on Archlinux. However on Archlinux, if the system has been asleep and physically not moved for a while and I physically move the system, this again causes the system to wake up, however the system does not go into an endless cycle of sleep and wake. Linux Kernel version of Archlinux was I believe 5.10.14-arch1-1.

BTW I am using Ubuntu 20.10 with the kernel version 5.8.0-43-generic.

Switching to Archlinux is not really an option, because while Archlinux fixed the sleep issue it also introduced a whole new set of issues like constant stutters, that I have no idea how to troubleshoot. Besides, I like Ubuntu.

This issue has been giving me headaches for a while now, because I really want to fully get rid of windows, which does not make a lot of sense while my system can't properly sleep on linux. I would be very grateful for any help, and I would also be happy to submit any logs or any other type of information that might help identify the issue.

Edit: Corrected the Arch kernel version to 5.10.14-arch1-1, my bad!

Edit2: I tried the latest kernel on the Ubuntu mainline PPA (v5.11-rc7). The new kernel did not fix the sleep issue but brought the problems I had on Archlinux, such as constant stutters.

Comment: there is no such thing as kernel 5.14, please edit your question with the actual version tried on Arch. For Ubuntu, if you want to try a newer kernel, for a test, use [the Ubuntu mainline PPA](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/?C=N;O=D). The current version to try is [this](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.11-rc7/) one, and it always a good idea as a way to know if the issue has already been solved upstream. Note: there is a lot of upstream sleep related activity, but I don't follow it.

Comment: Corrected the kernel version, and tried the current kernel on the link you provided, however that did not help.

Answer (score 0):

there's two things to consider here.

1. Is your system configured to suspend-then-hibernate? if that's the case then the system is waking up to hibernate, but it's failing in the process of hibernation, this can be caused by not having or having a small swap partition or swap file, if you don't want hibernation you can find more info here [How to go automatically from Suspend into Hibernate?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12383/how-to-go-automatically-from-suspend-into-hibernate)
    and instead of configuring the hibernation you disable it entirely or you can test if the solution of that question solves your problem.
2. Some Intel Haswell systems with the LynxPoint and LynxPoint-LP chipset sufer from instantaneous wakeups from suspend if that's the case you can se the archlinux solution for this (yes i know this is for the ubuntu os but scince you don't have that specific probem in arch maybe this is why) [instantaneous wakeups from suspend](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management/Suspend_and_hibernate#Instantaneous_wakeups_from_suspend)

Still this requires more digging and more specific info, but this may point you to the right direction to solve the problem.

Comment: I believe my system does not have hibernate enabled at all. Also I my system has a i7 1165G7 tiger lake processor.