# Failed to suspend system, hibernate later via logind: Sleep verb "suspend-then-hibernate" not supported

Tags: 22.04, suspend, power-management, hibernate

I tried to activate suspend then hibernate feature on my ubuntu 22.04. I followed the instruction of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1075860/716240), but unfortunately when I run `sudo systemctl suspend-then-hibernate` return error:

> Failed to suspend system, hibernate later via logind: Sleep verb "suspend-then-hibernate" not supported

I activated suspend-then-hibernate in the `sleep.conf`. Here it contains:

```
[Sleep]
AllowSuspend=yes
AllowHibernation=yes
AllowSuspendThenHibernate=yes
AllowHybridSleep=yes
#SuspendMode=
#SuspendState=mem standby freeze
#HibernateMode=platform shutdown
#HibernateState=disk
#HybridSleepMode=suspend platform shutdown
#HybridSleepState=disk
HibernateDelaySec=50min
```

My laptop is a Lenovo Thinkbook 14 G2. Is my laptop not supporting `suspend-then-hibernate` feature? Or I missing something?

### update:

Prior to that I had 10GB swap, but now I upgraded to 16 swap and still not working.

```
(base) mycom@mycom:~$ free -h
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15Gi       5,4Gi       5,4Gi       1,1Gi       4,6Gi       8,6Gi
Swap:           15Gi          0B        15Gi
```

When I run `systemctl hibernate` also returns a similar error:

> Failed to hibernate system via logind: Sleep verb "hibernate" not supported

Comment: Do you have a swap partition? How much RAM do you have? What is the size of the swap partition?

Comment: @user68186 I have 16GB RAM and 10GB swap partition.

Comment: You need a bigger swap partition. 1.25 times the RAM. The whole comments of the RAM must fit in the swap plus whatever may be in the swap at that time. Search this site for his to increase the swap partition. The process is harder for encrypted partitions. Update the question after increasing swap if the problem continues.

Comment: I didn't see the updated question when I wrote the above comment. The other possibility is this motherboard does not support Linux hibernate. Hibernate is not enabled by default in Ubuntu because it does not work in many computers.